# Create and add a table inside a tablecell

Tags: html, asp.net

I am trying create a table and add this table into tablecell (table inside table in short)

It seems to be working with pure html and Javascript but it does not seem to work with asp.net table. I have tried to add other controls to the particular cell, like adding labels, htmldiv, textboxes and they all work fine except table.

Does anyone how to to achieve this by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you right here is an example:

```
<asp:Table runat="server">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Table runat="server">
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am trying to do dynamically and on the cell I do 
cell.Controls.add(newTable).
And this does not appear on the page.